# mysql table layout has me completely baffled

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a database that will match up care workers to clients. The carers visit the clients and assist them to get dressed etc. So the carer table holds there information such as what gender they are do they drive etc. If a client wants a female carer then I would check to see the gender of the relevant carer and all male carers would be excluded. I started down this route with my tables but soon discovered there was lots of combinations of questions and answers.

I don't know if this requires a many to many relationship but I'm a bit lossed off.
Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: Use a general attribute-value table.

Comment: **Suggestion:** Create **Users** Table.....Create a **Roles** Table and create a relationship between them. Keep all kinds of Users in the Users Table. By doing the above, you will reduce the complexity for the future purposes. :-) ( Anything else to be asked ??? ) @user2042410

Comment: Sounds like a typical many-to-many 3 table case.

Comment: Thanks Malik for your help. Sometimes the clients don't require a driver but I still want the carers that can drive included. Its very confusing for me to figure this out.

Comment: While the guilt trip in the revision is probably uncalled for, you came to the right place to ask. It's how you are asking that is a problem. By showing no code or really other significant effort, you make all the people who volunteer their time here much less likely to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [bridge entity](http://databasemanagement.wikia.com/wiki/Database_Entities_in_E/R_Modeling) to eliminate the many to many relationship between your `Carer` and `Client` tables. This `Transaction` table would also allow you to add additional transaction-based information to that entity such as `Driver`, etc... that wouldn't belong with either the `Carer` or `Client`.

Something like this:

**Carer**

```
Carer_ID     PK
Name
Gender
Address
Vendor_ID     FK   -- Assuming your individual carers are part of a network
etc... Other Carer based details
```

**Client**

```
Client_ID    PK
Name
Address
Gender
etc... other Client based details
```

**Transaction**

```
Transaction_ID   PK
Client_ID        FK
Carer_ID         FK
DateTime
Location
Driver_ID        FK    -- Assuming you want to add a driver table
etc... Other transaction based details
```

**As a follow-up**... I personally disagree with those recommending the [Entity-Attribute-Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) design. EAV might be okay for basic look-up values in a front end application but basing your overall database design on it is a very bad idea (for integrity and maintenance reasons). It is much better to follow standard relational [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) practices and create an entity table for each of your primary actors.